# I get 404 for all pages in local wordpress installation except admin

Tags: wordpress

I have local version of wordpress, installed via windows web installer,
so I have IIS Express 8 and Webmatrix 3. After some modification of website (no idea what caused), I have all pages with 404 error. Except home page, I have 403.14 – Forbidden and it tries to open index.php in \My Web Sites\Wordpress folder, so, basically it is 404 as well. I can connect to login, admin page. I basically tried out everything I had found on first two pages of google, so I came here for advice. Is there any way to fix it?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...

I accidentally deleted index.php from root. Got new from clean install. Works.